# Understanding a proof of Hölder's inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Wikipedia outlines a nice proof of [Holder's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Proof_of_H.C3.B6lder.27s_inequality) in the link provided.

The fifth sentence in the proof reads:

> Dividing $f$  and $g$ by $\|f \|_p$ and $\|g\|_q$, respectively, we can assume
>   that $\|f\|_p = \|g\|_q = 1$.

**Question:** Why is this so?

**Attempt:** I do understand that

$$
\left\| {f \over \|f\|_p} \right\|_p = 1 = \left\| {g \over \|g\|_q} \right\|_q
$$

But I'm not sure exactly how that help us here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because afterwards you prove that if $\|f\|_p=\|g\|_q=1$, then $\|fg\|_1\leq1$. So
$$
\left\|\frac f{\|f\|_p}\,\frac g{\|g\|_q}\right\|_{1}\leq1,
$$
and multiplying by $\|f\|_p\|g\|_q$ you get the inequality. ${}{}$